# Installation Error of Sysmon on Windows 7 VM - Sysmondrv Driver and StartService Issue

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, drivers, virtual-machine, services

I hope you are doing well.

My issue is that I need to download and install Sysmon and need to perform scripts from the Invoke-Adversary emulation scripts (https://github.com/CyberMonitor/Invoke-Adversary). I am trying to do this on a Windows 7 VM on VirtualBox that was from the Microsoft Edge testing VMs page: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/. 
[IE10 Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDK86.jpg)

I am using the IE10 Windows 7 version. My issue is that I am trying to install sysmon after downloading it from the Microsoft site. I have put the sysmon.exe file and the configuration script from https://github.com/SwiftOnSecurity/sysmon-config in the same folder, and I have tried to use several variations of this command:

```
sysmon.exe -i
```

or

```
sysmon.exe -i -accepteula sysmonconfig-export.xml
```

However, the installation keeps going like this:

[image: Installation error]

Sysmon installed
SysmonDrv installed
Start Service failed for SysmonDrv:

Failed to start the driver:

Stopping he service failed:
The service has not been started
SysmonDrv removed
Stopping the service failed
The service has not been started
Sysmon removed

I have been stuck with this problem for several hours, I have tried to search up the solution to this issue online but there was not any I could find for this issue. I am running the command prompt in admin mode and I have checked that sysmon or sysmondrv are not already on the VM.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Update: I still have this issue with trying to install Sysmon on the Windows 7 VM, however I tried to download and install Sysmon on a Windows 8 VM and that went successfully using the same files and command(s) above. However, the solution to this problem still eludes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [this Microsoft fix - KBxxxx](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46148), I had this issue as well.
The [original source was this](https://blog.huntresslabs.com/troubleshooting-procmon-sysmon-v3-32-c4397dc75f50).

Comment: Are there any updates for this on Windows 10? It appears that KB3033929 patch has already been applied in Windows 10 and sigcheck states the signature is valid.